# Nested copy/paste loop in VBA not looping correctly

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code:

```
Sub Pitchers()

For i = 1 To 30

Worksheets("Starting Pitchers Salary").Range("B" & (1 + i)).Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Paste
Destination = Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B3")

For j = 1 To 9

Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("A" & (32 + j)).Copy
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Batter Matchup Analysis").Range("B88:AC88").Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("C" & (32 + j) & ":AD" & (32 + j)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next j

Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("A65:S65").Copy
Worksheets("Pitcher Comparison").Range("A" & (1 + i) & ":S" & (1 + i)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i

End Sub
```

Everything besides the below is working correctly

```
Worksheets("Starting Pitchers Salary").Range("B" & (1 + i)).Copy
```

When it loops, it doesn't go one cell down. In the first loop it copies cell B2 (as it should), but in subsequent loops it should be copying cell B3, B4, etc. but it does B2 each time. Any advice here?

Answer (score 0):

> `Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Paste`
>
> `Destination = Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B3")`

Change the above into this:

```
Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Paste _
    Destination := Worksheets("Pitcher Matchup Analysis").Range("B3")
```